# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Tags: python, pandas, time, binance, ta-lib

I would like to calculate the RSI figure once again in SMA and process it.
However, an error similar to the subject occurs. " AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'rolling' "

```
import talib
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

class RSI:
    def rsi(symbol, timeinterval, limit, period):
            
            coin = Can.get_fu_coin(symbol, timeinterval, limit)
            
            coin['close'] = coin['close'].astype(float)
            data = coin['close']
            
            period = period
            
            delta = data.diff()
            
            up, down = delta.copy(), delta.copy()
            up[up < 0] = 0
            down[down > 0] = 0
            
            _gain = up.ewm(com = (period - 1), min_periods = period).mean()
            _loss = down.abs().ewm(com = (period - 1), min_periods = period).mean()
        
            RS = _gain / _loss
        
            rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + RS))
            rsi = rsi.iloc[-1]
            rsi = round(rsi, 4)
            
            return rsi
    
    def rma(symbol, timeinterval, limit, period, n):
        data = RSI.rsi(symbol, timeinterval, limit, period).rolling(n)
        return talib.SMA(data,n)

RSI.rma('BTCUSDT', '1m', '1000', 14, 7)
```

Comment: `RSI.rsi()` clearly returns a float and the first line of `rma` calls `.rolling` on it, so the error seems straightforward and expected.  Are you trying to call pandas' [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)?  Maybe the last line before the return in `.rsi()` should be a pandas function instead of the `round` builtin?  Like [`DataFrame.round()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)?

Comment: When you remove rolling, you can see the following: TypeError:Argument 'real' has inaccurate type (expected number.ndarray, got number).float64" message appears.
I'm sorry. It hasn't been a month since I studied python myself.